# Shifting Date time index

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to shift my date time index such that 2018-04-09 will show as 2018-04-08 one day ahead and only shifting the last row, I tried a few ways with different error such as below:

```
df.index[-1] = df.index[-1] + pd.offsets.Day(1)
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

Can you kindly advise a suitable way please?

My df looks like this:

```
           FinalPosition 
dt                                       
2018-04-03          1.32              
2018-04-04           NaN              
2018-04-05           NaN              
2018-04-06           NaN              
2018-04-09           NaN
```

Comment: what about timedelta ?

Comment: I tried df.index[-1] = df.index[-1] - pd.Timedelta(days=1) which returns smiliar type error

Comment: Using df.index[-1] = df.index[-1].shift(-1, freq = 'D'), I return an attribute error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rename` if values of `DatetimeIndex` are unique:

```
df = df.rename({df.index[-1]: df.index[-1] + pd.offsets.Day(1)})
print (df)
            FinalPosition
dt                       
2018-04-03           1.32
2018-04-04            NaN
2018-04-05            NaN
2018-04-06            NaN
2018-04-10            NaN
```

If possible not unique for me working [`DatetimeIndex.insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.insert.html):

```
df.index = df.index[:-1].insert(len(df), df.index[-1] + pd.offsets.Day(1))
```

Comment: @Jerrick - Glad can help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.iloc`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": ["2018-04-09"]})
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
print df["datetime"].iloc[-1:] - pd.offsets.Day(1)
```

**Output:**

```
0   2018-04-08
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: df.index.iloc[-1:] - pd.offsets.Day(1) .. Hi Rakesh I tried this but get AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: Can you post your DF?

Comment: Ok just posted the df

Comment: can you try `.loc[-1:] - pd.offsets.Day(1)`